# Do I have to deallocate memory when I get a pointer to a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I'm currently learning the new c++ stuff, and I'm currently learning to use smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`).

Lets say I have a `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr`. At one point in my code, I need to iterate through this stl vector and pick out objects that I need for calculation.

```
  for (const auto& obj : objectList)
  {
    if(/*check if this is an object I need*/)
      OtherFunc(obj.get());
  }

  void OtherFun(object* obj)
  {
     std::vector tempVector.push_back(obj);
  }
```

In the OtherFunc, I add this object passed in as a parameter to another `std::vector`(denoted as otherVector) that I keep and do calculation. I dont want the `OtherFunc` to have ownership of the objects. I just need to keep them so I dont have to pass in the objects every frame.

I know smart pointers will de-allocate themselves if they leave the scope (or in my case, exits the program), what happens to the otherVector that contains object*s of the objects that are smart pointers. I tried looking at the documentations at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/get/) but I wasnt able to get an answer to my question. Will I have to de-allocate all of the object* that I have saved in my otherVector? Or since the objects are originally smart pointers, I can assume that all of the pointers in otherVector will also become null (hence, not causing a memory leak).

Comment: cpluscplus.com isn't a great site -  prefer cppreference.com

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but just to be sure: You know that you have to deallocate each *objcet* exactly once (as opposed to doing one deallocation per pointer pointing to the object)? The `std::unique_ptr` will do that for you.

Comment: In your code, `otherFunc` "observes" the pointer, it should not make any copies of nor store any references to `obj`, and should not delete it

Comment: If you need to have multiple, persistent references to the same object then use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`

Comment: Something to think about... when your vector of smart pointers goes out of scope, all of those smart-pointers will have their destructor called, and therefore will deallocate all of the memory they point to. Your "OtherFun" may not know that has happened, and attempt to dereference a pointer to now invalid memory. Just because your "OtherFun" doesn't own that memory or delete those objects, this is a very loose coupling which can lead to issues. Is there a way you can structure your data and data-passing to be more bulletproof?

Comment: @M.M Is it not? I just prefer it over cppreference because its a bit more visually better to look at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Documentation for `get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) will state that it simply returns a non-owner pointer to the managed resource, as opposed to `release()`, which actually transfers ownership to the returned pointer.

This is enough to answer your question with you **shouldn't** clean up that pointer. However, there are some other gotchas to be aware of.

Firstly, you must be cautious about **lifetime**. It is still the smart pointer's job to manage the resource. If the smart pointer cleans up, that raw pointer will dangle. Make sure that the smart pointer outlives the raw one. If you cannot do that, you should use `shared_ptr`, which ensures that the resource is only cleaned up when all associated smart pointers are done with it.

Now there are two ways you can use `shared_ptr` for this task. Both require changing the type of smart pointer in the original vector to `shared_ptr`. To preface this, imagine you are taking this pointer and storing it for later use. By the time it's used, the original vector might be gone and the smart pointers inside it gone with it. I'm also assuming you require a raw pointer for the operation you do with the resource. Perhaps you need to give it to a C function.

1. Use it directly. This is good if you want the resource to stick around at least as long as whatever `OtherFun` uses it for needs it. `OtherFun` will take a `shared_ptr`, which can now be created by passing the vector element directly without using `get`.

   Using `get` here will, in fact, cause a bug because `shared_ptr` needs to be constructed from another `shared_ptr` in order to have proper reference counting on the resource. `OtherFun` stores `shared_ptr` in whatever needs it and that stored pointer ensures the resource won't die when the original vector does.

   When it's time to access the resource, you get the raw pointer you need from the `shared_ptr` and ensure the local `shared_ptr` outlives the use of this raw pointer, which is much easier than ensuring it outlives the vector element.
2. Store `weak_ptr`. This is good if you want the original vector to be the only one in charge of the resource, but need to be able to check whether the resource is still valid and use it if it is. `OtherFun` will store a `weak_ptr` in whatever needs it. If the original vector dies, the resource will, too.

   When the resource needs to be used from elsewhere, a `shared_ptr` is obtained from the `weak_ptr` using `lock` (giving a possibly empty `shared_ptr`) or `shared_ptr`'s converting constructor from `weak_ptr` (throwing a possible exception). You check appropriately whether the resource is still there and the `shared_ptr` ensures it will remain there until you're finished. At that point, you can continue like option 1 and get the raw pointer you need.

Apart from all of that, you must be careful with **ownership**. The raw pointer from `get()` must never turn into an owner of any sort. For example, the following is **wrong** and will cause a double delete of the pointer:

```
void OtherFun(object* obj)
{
    std::unique_ptr<object> p(obj);
}
```

Here, you've given unique ownership of `*obj` to `p` even though the `unique_ptr` you called `get()` on still owns `*obj`. This is similar to the aforementioned `shared_ptr::get()` trap, where you end up with two unassociated `shared_ptr`s managing the same resource.

`get()` is inherently somewhat unsafe and breaks encapsulation. However, it is also necessary in order for smart pointers to be practical for real-world use. Just be aware that you can fall into traps, both from lifetime when you obtain a raw pointer, and if you end up turning that non-owning raw pointer into an owner. This is what the `release()` function is for. In general, you're considerably safer when you don't need raw pointers from smart pointers and when you treat raw pointers as non-owners only.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the other vector as `std::vector<object*>`.  It will hold object pointers but will not own them, so it will not try to free the objects when itself is freed.  The objects will be freed when the original `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<object>>` is freed.  Just make sure the original vector outlives the other vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a pointer to what's inside `std::unique_ptr` to take a "peek", but this is invisible to the smart pointer. If the unique pointer goes out of scope and deletes its object, any ordinary pointers you had to its held object become invalid. So long as your regular pointers will not be used after the unique pointer has deleted the object, you are safe, but no protection is given!

If you need multiple pointers to an object with different lifetimes, consider `std::shared_ptr`.